# How to Send Emails Using SendGrid with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sendgrid

I'm looking for a code that allows me to send emails using SendGrid api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to send emails using SendGrid.

```
import sendgrid

sg = sendgrid.SendGridClient('Username','Password')
message = sendgrid.Mail()

message.add_to("Email Address of Reciever")
message.set_from("Email Address of Sender")
message.set_subject("Email Subject")
message.set_html("Email html")

sg.send(message)
```

For full documentation check out https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/python.html